# Latency time to sometimes load css or js file to 5s on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost

I use windows 7 64 bit + xampp 1.74 (apache)
You can see in this picture:

http://www.pixhost.org/show/2206/6438394_capture.png

all that files is on localhost. it takes 5s to response. i checked
[Why is the response on localhost so slow?](https://serverfault.com/questions/66347/localhost-response-very-slow-why)
but it can't resolve this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the same with Firefox and Firebug if you have there the same problems?

- try to diable ipv6
- check the hosts file and print the lines for localhost here
- check **apache.conf** set the **HostnameLookups Off**

Comment: i disabled ipv6 and edit host file, but still remain matter.hostnameLooups default is OFF , i dont edit it.http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#HostnameLookups

Comment: i checked with firefox , firebug, it has same problem, too.